# How do I send Email using an email client?

Tags: android

I am trying to-

1. get my own primary email
2. set the primary email as recipient's address so I can send an email
       to Myself

This is how I get my primary email-

```
Pattern emailPattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS; // API level 8+
            Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(getBaseContext())
                    .getAccounts();
            for (Account account : accounts) {
                if (emailPattern.matcher(account.name).matches()) {
                    String possibleEmail = account.name;
                    Toast.makeText(this, possibleEmail, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }
```

and this is how I send email-

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            i.setType("message/rfc822");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                    new String[] { "recipient@example.com" });
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "body of email");
            try {
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(Main.this,
                        "There are no email clients installed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

How do I give `EXTRA_EMAIL` my primary email?

Comment: You need to have at least basic understanding of language, because just copy-paste programming is really bad way if you want to archive something in that area.

Comment: Note that there is no requirement for `AccountManager` to have a usable email address for the user.

Comment: @Divers too bad, I'm an athlete, and i'm doing this only cause I need music and only spotify works. i'm making an app which saves my spotify profile by Emailing it to myself and later i can get unlimited free trials and retrieve this saved profile so I never lose my playlist.

Comment: @joey then probably better to hire someone

Comment: @Divers I don't need it, I made the app already :DD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
    String possibleEmail = null;
    Pattern emailPattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS; // API level 8+
    Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(getBaseContext())
            .getAccounts();
    for (Account account : accounts) {
        if (emailPattern.matcher(account.name).matches()) {
            possibleEmail = account.name;
            Toast.makeText(this, possibleEmail, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    }

    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    i.setType("message/rfc822");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{possibleEmail});
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "body of email");
    try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(Main.this,
                "There are no email clients installed.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```